# Beacon Android keep scanning on every Activity

Tags: java, android, ibeacon-android

I need to show an alertDialog on every activity if I detect a beacon, I'm using Kontakt beacon with their android library, I got the code working for the MainActivity but If I copy the code to another activity I get no results.. Is this the right approch or should I create a global class that every of my activity uses? If so how can I show the alertDialog to the correct activity?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that you can use is to extend the Application class and put your ranging code in there instead.  If you do this you will be able to maintain a cache of ranged beacons that are accessible to the rest of the application while the app is open.  And you can just call the dialog from there.

Check your other Activities to make sure you remembered to call beaconManager.bind().

If so, debug in your rangeNotifier code to make sure you are actually ranging beacons as you think.  If you are then there is probably an issue with the dialog call.